# Grab all require calls from a file

Tags: node.js, require, node-modules

I'm writing a small Node.js module that does some stuff on a specific file.

I'm wondering if it's possible to grab the names of all modules that have been `require`'d - I looked through Browserify's codebase but I couldn't really get a grasp on what was happening.

As an example, say I have this file:

```
var fs    = require('fs'),
    chalk = require('chalk');

// Some code
var temp_dir = require('os-tmpdir')();
// Maybe some more code
```

Is it possible to read in this file (or filename) and get an output like:

```
['fs', 'chalk', 'os-tmpdir']
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just noticed the node module [required](https://github.com/defunctzombie/node-required).